# Image Processing Q: Separate/segment an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

need some help here on image processing. I'm using Matlab and try to segment the following figure based on the two major peaks (in yellow). The color yellow means higher value and blue means low value (on z-axis, or image color from 0 to 1 for your convenience). The ideal cut is roughly the line from point (1,75) to (120,105). But I want a systematic way to derive this rather than by observation.

[image]

My intuition was to first identify the two peaks (based on [this](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/06/02/cell-segmentation/)), and then classify each point/pixel on this figure to the two peaks (the metric here is to compute the shortest Euclidean distance to the edge of the two peaks).

[image]

And I end up with the following fig.

[image]

As you can see, the cut is pretty much a straight line, which I'm not quite satisfied. Maybe I can use the orientation of the peak circle and somehow tilt the line.. but I'm not sure how to do so? Any clues? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you working on an image instead of working on teh data that created that image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an Image segmentation problem.
you can use GMM Gaussian of Mixture Model to model the image.
in your case the number of components will be 2.
after you model the image by using this mixture, you can find the probability of each pixel P(pixel x belong to the first component or the second component)

check 
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/272162
http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/cluster-data-from-mixture-of-gaussian-distributions.html